# Slidedown an element onhover using jquery in a directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Given the following html and js I can't figure out how to get my element to show on hover.

**row of projects, my template file**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h1>Projects</h1>
      <div class="projects-body">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="project in projects">
          <div class="col-lg-4" ng-repeat="p in project">
            <div id="project-item-{{$index}}" class="thumbnail project-item" >
              <img src="{{p.img}}"></img>
              <div class="project-caption" slidetoggle ng-hide="true">
                {{p.short_desc}}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**my directive for toggling the .project-caption**

```
app.directive('slidetoggle', function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){

      element.parent().bind('mouseenter', function(){
        console.log('mouseenter parent:',  element.parent());
        element.show();
      });

      element.parent().bind('mouseleave', function(){
        console.log('mouseleave:', element);
        element.hide();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

when i mouseenter the element, i get the following undefined for `element.hide()` and `element.show()`

[image]

Comment: If you click on directives.js, what line is indicated as the problem?

Comment: sorry i should of stated that.. its the `element.show()` and `element.hide()` ....... even though logging them out i get the info i'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues. The first is that you need to show and hide jQuery objects. Change your statements to this:

```
$(element).show();
$(element).hide();
```

Then, `ng-hide` is overriding jQuery (or jQlite, as the case may be). Either use jQlite/jQuery, which use the display property, or use `ng-hide`, which adds the troublesome `!important` modifier, but not both.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/a312bL6r)**